# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR), expecting ')'

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, version

PHP is throwing an `unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR), expecting ')'` and I'm not sure why exactly.

```
if(empty($name || $mail || $mail2 || $tele)) {
    // do something ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. $empty() takes one only.

```
if(empty($name) || empty($mail) || empty($mail2) || empty($tele) );
```